# How to get the count of number of items in one table that are in another

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

For this example, we'll have 2 tables.  Table A and Table B.  Table A has all my data, and Table B has a list of numeric codes.  How can I select the count.  So far I have

```
select ID, count(Table A Codes that are in TableB) as SharedCodes
into #TableC
from #TableA
group by ID
```

What's the correct way to go about this?

Sample Data:
Table A:

```
ID      |  Code
----------------
1         A1
1         A2
1         A3
2         B1
2         B2
2         B3
3         C1
3         C2
3         C3
```

Table B:

```
Code
-----
A2
A3
B1
C1
C2
C3
```

So, the above query should return

```
ID      |   SharedCodes
-----------------------
1          2
2          1
3          3
```

Comment: sql server management studio 2008 r2

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: is the primary key for table a, b, c the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLEA TABLE (ID INT,Code VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @TABLEA VALUES
(1,'A1'),(1,'A2'),(1,'A3'),(2,'B1'),(2,'B2'),
(2,'B3'),(3,'C1'),(3,'C2'),(3,'C3')

DECLARE @TABLEB TABLE (Code VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @TABLEB VALUES
('A2'),('A3'),('B1'),('C1'),
('C2'),('C3')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT    A.ID 
         ,COUNT(B.Code) AS SharedCodes 
INTO     #TempTable
FROM     @TABLEA A INNER JOIN @TABLEB B 
ON       A.Code = B.Code
GROUP BY A.ID

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ SharedCodes ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║           2 ║
║  2 ║           1 ║
║  3 ║           3 ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```